# Firefox 47 - Application.activeWindow not working in addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

After upgrade to Firefox 47 `Application.activeWindow` is not working anymore.

It crashes at:

```
 var doc = Application.activeWindow.activeTab.document;
```

Any idea why? The addon had been working perfectly since last two years. If it is deprecated(and now removed) how to get the document object in the XUL addon.

Answer (score 1):

The reason being

```
Application.activeWindow
```

no more works in firefox 47. Instead of

- var doc = Application.activeWindow.activeTab.document;

we can also use

```
    var chromeWindow = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
    var doc = chromeWindow.content.document;
```

which does the same job.

So replacing `Application.activeWindow.activeTab.document` with  `content.document` fixed the issue.

I could find a deprecation warning page for the above in Firefox 40

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Toolkit_API/FUEL/fuelIWindow

Comment: I'm interested: When I try just `content.document` I find that `content` is not defined. What is your code to define `content`?

Comment: @Makyen On button press in XUL toolbar - I invoke a function which calls var doc = content.document;

Comment: Interesting.  I am testing in a restartless, XUL based add-on. The function is called from the handler of the command event for a Firefox toolbar button. In my case, `typeof content` = `"undefined"`.  Are you sure you do not define `content` somewhere else in your code?

Comment: @Makyen Mine is not a restartless adon - it is actually a firebug plugin similar to firepath. In XUL oncommand="window.myfunc()"

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Just keep in mind that it may not exist in other contexts/scopes.

Comment: `Application` is FUEL, the FUEL library was deprecated. Don't use it. Instead please use `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow(null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the document for the active tab of the most recently active window with:

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add/remove a "/" to comment/un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
    /* Add-on SDK:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/
    //* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
    var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                         .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");        
    //*/
}
if (typeof document === "undefined") {
    //If there is no document defined, get it
    var document = window.content.document;
}
```

This will work from almost any context.

You have stated in comments that this code is being run in response to the `command` event from a button.  Given that it is in an even handler you can use:

```
var window = event.view;
var document = window.content.document;
```

That `document` will be the HTML document for the current tab in the window in which the event took place.

For either of the above, you can get some additional objects which might be helpful with:

```
let gBrowser = window.gBrowser;
let primeDocument = window.document;//The primary document container for that Firefox window.
let mainXULWindow = window.document.getElementById("main-window");
```